# Definition of Thurston's skinning map

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

A key construction in Thurston's proof of the existence of hyperbolic structures on Haken manifolds is the so-called "skinning map" associated to a 3-manifold $M$ with boundary whose interior admits a hyperbolic metric. The map
$$\sigma_M:\mathrm{Teich}(\partial M) \to \mathrm{Teich}(\overline{\partial M})$$ takes a conformal structure on the boundary and produces a new one. Conformal structures on $\partial M$ are in bijection with geometrically finite hyperbolic metrics on $M$. See [here](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Ectm/papers/home/text/papers/rs/rs.pdf) for a quick reference.

The problem is, I'm having trouble understanding what exactly this map is. The most I've gathered is that one can lift a hyperbolic structure on $M$ to the covering space $\tilde M$ of the interior corresponding to the image of $\pi_1(\partial M)\to\pi_1(M)$, and that this induces a new conformal structure, but how? In particular, how can the covering space $\tilde M$ be described as a manifold? Is it just $\partial M\times \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let’s simplify to the case where $M$ has exactly one boundary component, say $\partial M = S$. So the hyperbolic structures on $M$ are parametrised by the conformal structures on $S$.  Fix one such conformal structure $\rho$ and lift the resulting hyperbolic structure on $M$ to the cover corresponding to $\pi_1(S)$. As you suggest, this cover is homeomorphic to $S \times \mathbb{R}$. So it has two ends, each giving a conformal structure on $S$. One of these is $\rho$, the conformal structure we started with.  The other is the (orientation reverse of) $\rho'= \sigma_M(\rho)$ - that is, the image of $\rho$ under the skinning map.

I believe that $\sigma_M$ is called the "skinning map" because $\rho \sqcup \rho'$ gives the "skin at infinity" of the lifted hyperbolic structure on $S \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I went back and reread and thought about this a little more to try and understand it. Am I correct to say that the subgroup of $\pi_1$ corresponding to a boundary component is quasi-Fuschian, and the two components of the domain of discontinuity are the ends?

Comment: Yes, that is all correct.  These deductions require Canary's covering theorem, given in the paper "A covering theorem for hyperbolic three-manifolds and its applications".

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, you should consider "accepting" it (by clicking the tick mark).